# How to remove multiple characters from a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file which contains a few columns with unwanted text which I want to remove. Could someone please help me on this?

Sorry about any confusions, here is the input file looks like:

```
TIME,P0,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5    
22:46:32,PS=P0:Spd=5000:Volt=1.26:SP=FFull,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600   
22:46:33,PS=P0:Spd=5000:Volt=1.26:SP=FFull,PS=P0:Spd=5000:Volt=1.26625:SP=FFull,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600   
22:46:34,PS=P0:Spd=5000:Volt=1.26:SP=FFull,PS=P0:Spd=5000:Volt=1.26625:SP=FFull,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600   
22:46:35,PS=P0:Spd=5000:Volt=1.26:SP=FFull,PS=P0:Spd=5000:Volt=1.26625:SP=FFull,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=P0:Spd=4800:Volt=1.24:SP>P0SP,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600,PS=M0:SPd=1600
```

Output file:

```
TIME,P0,Volt0,P1,volt1,P2,volt2,P3,volt3,P4,volt4,P5,volt5,D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5
22:46:32,5000,1.26,5000,1.26,4900,1.25,5000,1.26,5000,1.26,4900,1.25,1600,1600,1600,1600,1600,1600
22:46:33,4800,1.25,4900,1.15,5000,1.26,5000,1.26,5000,1.26,4900,1.25,1600,1600,1600,1600,1600,1600
22:46:34,5000,1.26,4900,1.25,4900,1.25,5000,1.26,5000,1.26,4900,1.25,1600,1600,1600,1600,1600,1600
22:46:35,5000,1.26,5000,1.26,5000,1.26,5000,1.26,5000,1.26,4900,1.25,1600,1600,1600,1600,1600,1600
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried and provide that snippet. it's not easy to imagine how your csv looks.

Comment: Read about extracting text with Regex+Python. There are tons of examples here on SO.

Comment: give at least 3 lines of your file.

Comment: Thanks and sorry about any confusion, i just uploaded the raw input data and the output data looks like. Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using regex and then creating a dataframe. You can learn more about regex on regex101.com. Here is a part of your problem: https://regex101.com/r/docq3i/1

```
import re
import pandas as pd

csvfile = """\
PS=P0:Spd=5000:Volt=1.26:SP=Full , PS=T0:Spd=1700
PS=P0:Spd=300:Volt=1.46:SP=Full , PS=T0:Spd=12000
"""

# Patterns to look for where (.*?) is unkown
patterns = ['P0:Spd=(.*?):Volt',
           ':Volt=(.*?):SP=Full',
           'T0:Spd=(.*?)\n']

# Extract values
values = [re.findall (x, csvfile, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL) for x in patterns]

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(values).T

# Output dataframe
df.to_csv("output.csv",index=False,header=None,sep=",")
```

Output.csv:

```
5000,1.26,1700
300,1.46,12000
```